# use of mkdir -p in c for creating parent folders of a file

Tags: c

I need a lead on this.
I am working on language translation using dgettext utility of glibc.
I have a file x.mo in a location eg: /usr/share/x.mo but dgettext work on directory structure  /usr/share/(language/mSG/)x.mo How can i create this intermidiate directory language/mSG in C.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Do you want to create the directory through C instead of shell commands is it ?You can see system api or popen api .

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [mkdir() UNIX function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html):

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
int mkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode);
```

But easier would be to use the [system() UNIX function](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?system):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int system(const char *command);
```

Something like this might work for you:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
   system("mkdir -p /usr/share/language/mSG");
   system("ln -s /usr/share/x.mo /usr/share/language/mSG");
}
```

Comment: Note: I got the ln -s arguments backwards at first but edited them to be in the correct order, also the file name part of the path is implied for the 2nd argument of ln -s so I omitted it.

Comment: is it possible to automatically create non-existent parent directory when making API call to `mkdir()` as if running `mkdir -p /PATH/TO/SOME/FOLDER` ? Or do I have to create every single parent directory one by one (if using `mkdir()`) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the **popen** or **system** api's to run the shell commands through the C code .

```
FILE *pf;
char command[512];

sprintf(command, "mkdir -p /usr/share/language/mSG");

pf = popen(command,"r"); 

if(!pf){
  fprintf(stderr, "popen failure \n");
  return;
}
```